# Is snus legal in Sweden?

Tags: legal, sweden

Have read on the internet that there's a tobacco product called snus that appears to be legal in Sweden while banned many countries.

Can you bring snus into Sweden and out of Sweden? Or will you be fined and have the snus confiscated if you do so?

---

**Snus** seems like some form of tobacco that you put under your lip and can also be sold as small packages.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it is only legal in Sweden.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snus

Comment: From a friend who lived in Sweden I have heard that it is very addictive, she said she could easily leave off cigarettes but had to have snus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not travel related, but about personal products.

Comment: LMFAO, snus is Swedish, so it'd be dreadful if it wasn't legal there

Comment: @Coke: And Heroin, by that name, is German, yet it's not freely available here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snus is definitely legal in Sweden. I know several Swedes who openly use it at work.

Wikipedia disagrees with your assessment on legality, saying only that it is banned in EU countries except Sweden. Wikipedia notes its use in the US. I have personally seen it on sale openly in Canada

Comment: More precisely, Wikipedia says that its **sale** is illegal in the whole of the EU except Sweden, not its possession or use. For example, the relevant [UK law](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1992/3134/made/data.xht?wrap=true) reads “No person shall supply, offer to supply, agree to supply, expose for supply or possess for supply any tobacco for oral use.” As far as I'm aware, personal use, import for personal use, and possession for personal use are all legal.